# How to remove timestamp from backups (want backups overwritten every night)

Tags: sql, backup

Running server 2008 R2 - SQL.
We have a scheduled task to run a batch file to scan and backup certain Directories and Files. We want these backups overwritten every night. Currently, a whole new backup will be created with a time stamp. Our remote backup software sees these files as new files every night, instead of writing over the current ones. We have limited space on the remote backup so we need the current ones written over every night. Can I add a parameter to our batch file that will create a static "timestamp"? Or can I point the batch file to another script that will automatically do this?

Comment: Can you show the batch file?

Comment: osql -S %SERVER% -d msdb /U (username) /P (password) -i "Nightly Maintenance 2008 SSE.sql" -o "Nightly Maintenance 2008 SSE log.txt"

Comment: The batch file is working properly, so are the backups. Basically what I'm trying to do is copy those backups (that have a timestamp) to a new folder, the files in this folder will have a static name so that our backup software knows every time, that it is the same file. The only issue I'm facing, is how am I suppose to copy the file without manually naming the file(because of the time stamps).